# Store the current user safely

Tags: angular, authentication, storage

I'm using angular 8 and I want to store my current user! I think that it is not practical at all to call the api everytime I want to get the current user, and it is not safe to save it in the local storage!
Any help?

Comment: take a look at `share`: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/share.html but remember to properly dispose this when user logs out.

Answer (score 0):

cache it in a service e.g.

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    user: User;
    getCurrentUser = (): Observable<User> =>
     this.user ?
        of(this.user) :
        this.http.get<User>(`${this.endpoint}/loggedinuser`)
            .pipe(tap(u => {
                this.user = u;
            }))
```

EDIT: The solution in the comment by @AJT82 using the share() operator is probably cleaner and better. However storing it in a variable has it's advantages, it's easier to logout (just do this.user = null) and it might be handy to have the user accessible just as a User property instead of an observable.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the option to store currentUser I hope this will help.

Basically you need to store current user in localStorage or sessionStorage.

For Ex:

```
this.http.get<any>('${this.endpointURL}/currentUser}).subscribe(res=>{

  // If you want to store token
  localStorage.setItem('current_user', res.authentication_token ) 

  // If you want to store complete user object
  localStorage.setItem('current_user', JSON.stringify(res.user) )
})
```

That's it. Happy Coding.